# Terraform 12 var and string concatenation best practice

Tags: terraform

I'm updating from terraform 0.11 to 0.12 and I was wondering what was the "best practice" to concatenate string and vars in my `.tf` files.

The new syntax is pretty straightforward reguarding the variables :

```
# V0.11
foo = "${var.bar}"

# V0.12
foo = var.bar
```

but how should-I handle this situation ?

```
foo = "${var.bar}-a-string"
```

Shall-I keep this syntax or turn it in something like :

```
foo = join("-", [${var.bar}, "a", "string"])
```

[This guy](https://medium.com/oracledevs/lessons-learned-when-upgrading-to-terraform-0-12-6d894d3ab20e?) seems to think we should keep interpolation syntax for string concatenation even if it's deprecated in the new terraform version.

Comment: Invoking a function to interpolate a simple string is not really going to be best practices in any language. The former listed usage is going to be more straightforward than the latter, and is the same usage you see in other similar declarative DSLs (Puppet, Jenkins Pipeline, etc.). Neither usage you listed is deprecated either, as the former is the documented usage, and the latter is an indirect method of achieving the same result.

Comment: String interpolation is certainly not deprecated in 0.12. It's only made unnecessary when using the variable itself - ie. instead of having to do `some_prop = "${var.value}"` you can now do `some_prop = var.value`.

Comment: Thank's for the feedback, will keep string interpolation in this case then !

Answer (score 1):

To concatenate variable with the string, use this syntax instead of join() :

`foo = "string-${var.bar}-a-string"`

But if you don't want to use a variable for string concatenation, you can use such syntax:

`foo = var.bar`